# Azure Functions - Create from existing console app

Tags: azure-functions

I have a console app on ironworker I'd like to port to azure functions.

I was wondering the best way to go about this.

It uses ninject, email, FTP and other external libraries to hook in to shopify. I was wondering what you'd suggest?

Currently a webhook loads the job payload in to ironMQ which retries 5 times if the worker fails. Is there some kind of Azure consultant you can chat to to get advice on porting solutions?

If using an existing exe with functions would you upload the exe and have something like powershell in functions call the exe with a payload? or what is the suggested approach?

I can't seem to find much on this on the azure site.

Also where do you then store your .config file settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to make changes to the operation of this code, I'd suggest writing a C# or nodejs function using the necessary libraries for your shopify integration. Otherwise, uploading the exe and running with powershell seems like a reasonable solution.

In Functions, a good pattern for the retry behavior you desire is a QueueTrigger. Payloads will be automatically [retried / sent to a poison queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#a-idpoisona-how-to-handle-poison-messages) upon failure.

Here is the [azure tech support site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/)

Settings that would typically be placed in your .config file are handled through configuration using the portal (App Settings) and may work with the same set of configuration APIs. Functions can also handle configuration via functions.json / environment variables / config files in the function directory.

Comment: Thanks Matt I'll give it a whirl :)